# Unity error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with my code in Unity and can't decide it by myself.
Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;

[Serializable]
public class PlayerVoice
{
public int voiceSnap;
public string voiceValue;
}


public class GetVoice : MonoBehaviour
{
public static GetVoice instance;

public PlayerVoice[] playerVoice;
public int[] snaps;
public string[] voiceChangeValue;


public void Awake()
{
    instance = this;
}

public void LoadVoice()
{
        var count = MainInfo.instatnce.mainCount;
        playerVoice = new PlayerVoice[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            playerVoice[i].voiceSnap = snaps[i];
            playerVoice[i].voiceValue = voiceChangeValue[i];
        }
}
}
```

But in starting scene I get error in this line

```
playerVoice[i].voiceSnap = snaps[I];
```

this is error text from console

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> GetVoice+d__43.MoveNext () (at Assets/Script/GetVoice.cs:36)

if I change playerVoice Length into inspector, the problem is resolved.
I can't understand why I catch this error. Help please

Comment: `playerVoice = new PlayerVoice[count];` - You've create a new array of objects, but have put no objects in that array.  It's just a placeholder for storing `PlayerVoice` objects.  Essentially you need to create a new `PlayerVoice` object at any given index of `i` before you can use that object.

Comment: @David Thank you. How create a new `PlayerVoice` object at any given index of `I`? I thought that the object was already created

Comment: `playerVoice[i] = new PlayerVoice();`

Comment: I don't know for certain if this is the *ideal* approach since I'm not familiar with the architecture of designs here, but at its simplest it could just be `playerVoice[i] = new PlayerVoice();` as the first operation in your loop.  (Assuming `PlayerVoice` has a parameterless constructor.  Use whatever you would for creating a new instance of that object.)

Comment: Thanks to you, I figured out how it should work. Thank u

Comment: Why don't you just configure them accordingly right in the Inspector? Instead of in the completely independent two arrays .. your class is already serialized anyway so why not directly use that?